# Getting value of a property in another declaration

Tags: stylus

Within a declaration, how can one programmatically get the value of a property of an element in another declaration?

For example, take the following:

```
.header {
  height: 50px
}

.footer {
  margin-top: // TODO a method for retrieving ".header" height should go here
}
```

Is there some method for getting, for example, the value of `.header`'s height with `.footer`'s declaration? Something like `getProperty('height', '.header')`?

(I'm trying to avoid creating a variable to handle this if possible.)

Comment: Don't spam unrelated tags with your question.  This question has nothing to do with Sass, LESS, or CSS.  This is a pure Stylus problem.  Do not ask about more than one language in your question unless the implementation is guaranteed to be identical (hint: it's not).

Comment: It does now—refresh your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SASS and LESS have no such ability to get other declarations' properties.

Stylus can programmatically get values of other properties within the same declaration or its ancestors if nested (see [documentation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/variables.html#property-lookup)), but it can't get the values of properties elsewhere (see [explanation](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/559)).

So the solution is identical to all three preprocessors: Introduce a variable (or a mix-in).

Comment: Why are you even mentioning unrelated languages in your answer?

Comment: Questions aren't *supposed* to be about multiple unrelated languages at once.  If you'd done your homework, you would have already seen that there are multiple questions regarding this for Sass.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with my question—time to move on.